# PHP gettype returning double instead of integer?

Tags: php

On my local machine the following returns `double` instead of `integer`:

```
echo gettype(1625871600000);
```

This only happens on my Windows 10 machine (it's a 64-bit PC). I'm running MAMP with PHP 7.4.1. On Mac running MAMP with the same PHP version, the same expression returns integer. What could be causing this discrepancy? This is causing errors in some packages I'm running where the number is expected to be int, not float/double.

Comment: What is the result of `echo PHP_INT_SIZE;` you get from both your systems?

Comment: PHP_INT_SIZE is 4 on Windows, 8 on Mac.